# Spring Security: Get JWT from either Authorization or Cookie

Tags: cookies, spring-security, jwt, http-headers

We have built an application that, until recently, accepted authentication using the OAuth 2.0 pattern.  Users sign in to a Client web site that collaborates with an Authentication Server to get a JWT.  The Client web site includes that JWT as an Authorization Bearer header in each request to our Resource Server application.  The Resource Server, written with Spring Security 5.3, handles retrieving the Authentication Server's JWKS, approving the JWT, and setting the User's roles.  This was not too difficult.

We are trying to enable a Swagger UI page that is hosted directly by the Resource Server (the Client web site is built and deployed separately).  We are trying to provide two different methods to accessing and using the Swagger UI securely.  Unfortunately, it seems that both require using Cookies as opposed to Authorization Bearer headers:

1. The Authentication Server providers have provided a gateway to log into our Swagger UI page "directly".  The request for the page provides a JWT as a Cookie.  We will confirm with this team later today whether they can change this or not.  That might be a moot point, though, because...
2. We are implementing a link through our Client web site to reach the Swagger UI.  We have not found any method to redirect that allows us to include headers.  We seem forced to use cookies.

Naturally, we want to add the support for retrieving JWTs from Cookies (potentially with two different names) without losing the Authorization Bearer method that is currently deployed and used.

I have tried and failed to find any examples or tutorials that explain how we can extract JWTs from a Cookie at all, let alone supporting both methods at the same time.

How can we do this?

Comment: you are not providing sufficient information. Authentication can not be provided through a JWT cookie. JWT is just a format for storing information. And a cookie is a file on a client and its content is included during a request. You supplied no information as to how the authentication is performed. Is it by username password. `We have not found any method to redirect that allows us to include headers. We seem forced to use cookies.` what redirects, who is redirecting? proxy? too little information.

Comment: `The Authentication Server providers have provided a gateway to log into our Swagger UI page "directly".` who is the provider, what type of authentication, oauth2, basic login, SAML, form login.

Comment: extracting information from a cookie is like any cookie, you read the cookie from the request and parse its content. But remember, everything you are mentioning here is completly non-standard, and it is ALWAYS bad practice to implement custom security in any way shape or form. Security standards exists just because of the constant bad implementations of poor security with constant security breaches every day. Is that a risk you can accept?

Comment: @Toerktumlare , please see the first paragraph.  I am not giving the specifics of our configuration because you have no need to know, and our configuration that uses the standard Spring Security JOSE-based OAuth 2.0 implementation works.
I am uncertain what method the gateway will use for method #1, but they claim they can send the Authorization header.
We need to use either `window.location = 'URL';` or `window.open('URL');` for method #2.  This is JavaScript.

Comment: And as i pointed out, this question can not be answered with the unsufficient information provided. I am fully aware of how javascript and oauth2 works. And i would help but there is not enough information. Good luck